# Why is the Visual Studio 2015 build not finding assemblies added to new (.NET 4.0) GAC?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, gac

The Visual Studio 2015 build process is not finding assemblies added to new (.NET 4.0) GAC.

Adding the assemblies was fine, and they show up in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
```

And the references appear to be correct at design time BUT when I try to build it fails as if the reference is missing.

In case it might be related to the problem, I am working with SSIS script packages - .dtsx files.

NOTE: The build process is finding the assemblies I installed in the old GAC at build time, just not the ones in the new GAC!

Why might this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add reference, usually the `third-party .dll` cannot solve the problem, you need to register the global assembly cache manually. Here are the steps:

step 1: Launch the `command prompt for VS` with Administrator

step 2: change directory `cd` to your reference folder, which is

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
```

step 3: then register the assembly by `gacutil /i name of the dll.dll`

step 4: restart your visual studio

Comment: Thanks @LONG but the various files are already installed in the GAC. And VS is finding them there fine at design time, but when I build it seems to lose those that are in the new GAC.

Comment: It happens when you are trying to use third-party dll, if you are trying to download any from Nuget package manager, as far as I know, it will download in cache temp folder at design time, (I assume you are saying the C# script task), after you close and reopen the task, it will disappear, that is probably related to `register` step. Even you have copy and put the downloaded dll in your own folder, you can not still let the package run well before you register it in GAC.

Comment: This is actually not a third party DLL, but one that needs to be in the GAC for reasons that are not important here. I installed it there, and Visual Studio finds it at design time, but doe not find it at build time.